# Создание экземпляров первого класса во втором

Tags: python-3.x, классы, graph

Имеются два класса. В методе AddEdge класса FlowNetwork создаются экземпляры класса Edge. Однако выдает ошибку KeyError: 's' в self.adj[u].append(edge).Помогите.,пожалуйста, понять в чем ошибка

```
class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, u, v, w):
        self.source = u
        self.target = v
        self.capacity = w

    def __repr__(self):
        return  (self.source, self.target, self.capacity)

class FlowNetwork(object):

  def  __init__(self):
    self.adj = {}
    self.flow = {}

  def AddEdge(self, u, v, w = 0):
    edge = Edge(u, v, w)
    redge = Edge(v, u, 0)
    edge.redge = redge
    redge.redge = edge
    self.adj[u].append(edge)
    self.adj[v].append(redge)
    self.flow[edge] = 0
    self.flow[redge] = 0
g = FlowNetwork()
g.AddEdge('s', 'p', 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.adj.setdefault(u, []).append(edge)
self.adj.setdefault(v, []).append(redge)
```

Ключи не создаются автоматически при обращении (только при присваивании), а если бы и создавались, то почему значениями по умолчанию были бы обязательно списки?

В python есть специальный словарь, в котором ключи создаются автоматически, но проблем это может создать больше чем решить.

```py
>>> defdict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [])
>>> defdict['x'].append(1)
>>> defdict['y'].append(2)
>>> print(defdict['z'])
[]
>>> print(defdict)
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fc5a8fd79d8>, {'x': [1], 'y': [2], 'z': []})
```